# Apache Felix Stateless Service

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I am recently looking into OSGI and Apache Felix. In my project I want to use a stateless service, but cannot find a way to do so.

Is it possible to create stateless service in Apache Felix?

If yes, can it be done using Felix Dependency Manager?

Comment: Can you describe (specifically) what you mean by "a stateless service?"

Comment: Something like EJB stateless session bean. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjg.html

Comment: @SHasan What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not much, just trying to do the things i do with java ee or spring. like static web resources (html, javascript), servlets, rest resources, jpa and services (Session beans/ Spring beans). I have used **Amdatu** and **Apache Felix**. Did not used **Activator** classes to serve services, instead used **@Component** annotation from **Felix Dependency Manager** bundle. Have used **@ServiceDependency** annotation to inject the service. So far everything worked, but now i want to know if i can use the different scopes  like **stateful, stateless, singleton, request..** as i can do in EJB or Spring.

Comment: @SHasan Then you need to ask a more specific question. OSGi Services are stateless until you add state to them.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and yes.

Here is how to make a stateless service in OSGi:

1. Make a service.
2. Don't add any state.

Comment: If only more answers were this succinct.

Comment: @SeanBright TBH I was struggling with SO's minimum character count!